# Android facebook send challenge/app request to friends

Tags: facebook, publish, send

Can I send challenges or app request to my friends without submitting my facebook app for review? The app status is live, taken out of sandbox. Added necessary fields. Now I can successfully login with my app, get user details, friends details, update status etc.

Do i need to create actions inside my app to get send request permission? I have created some actions too.

But when i send challenge, i can choose friends and send challenge. But they are not receiving! Tried requestPublishPermission() etc before sending challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can successfully login, fetch details and send request but no notification is receiving at the other end, then you probably did not fill the canvas urls.

Comment: Yes I dint fill up the canvas urls. Solved issue. Thanks :)

Comment: hi @ArunJose, can you help me out with this facebook related post?


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810267/challenge-brag-and-challenge-score-in-friend-smash-tutorial