# challenge_brag and challenge_score in Friend Smash tutorial

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

With reference to the Friend Smash tutorial as https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/unity/unity-tutorial what is the relevance of the challenge_brag parameter in the FB.Feed call and the challenge_score parameter in the FB.AppRequest call? As far as I can see they are not explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are just custom parameters that go back to the game.  It allows you to pass data through a request so you can handle it when the request is accepted and the invitee goes into the game.  You can then call FB.GetDeepLink() to retrieve these params.

Comment: I did the same thing and I'm also getting success response BUT when I call FB.GetDeepLink() I get -

"https://m.facebook.com /appcenter/com_my_game?fbs=1001&request_ids=1637907449790398%2C429544173898141%2C890827127675301&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user"


How can I handle this request?

Comment: Guys, any clues for this one?